# hibernate.cfg.xml of Hibernate

Tags: hibernate, hibernate.cfg.xml

In my Java Project, **hibernate.cfg.xml**
is sitting in the source folder-- \src. So, to be precise, it is a file in the source folder, sitting right next to the 
source codes.

However, Eclipse can't see it. Please see for [Hibernate -- object creation error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17456633/hibernate-object-creation-error) for the 
background of this Q.

My jar files are/should be in right places. And the header of **hibernate.cfg.xml** is the exact copy of one of the config files out of the installation package.

I am seeing the same error log with and without **hibernate.cfg.xml** in the project-- that's how I know it's not being processed on.

Where should **hibernate.cfg.xml** be ???

Answer (score 0):

By default hibernate will look at hibernate.cfg.xml on your classpath root. If you're packaging a jar, this is typically right at the top level. For war, typically on WEB-INF/classes.

If you eclipse is set with src folder as a source directory then it should be fine, just double check the generated war/jar has this file at correct location

Try refreshing / cleaning your eclipse project as often the resource is out of sync with file system.

Also have a look at [Configuration class](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.2/javadocs/org/hibernate/cfg/Configuration.html), it has `configure(String)` method to specify a custom location

Comment: whose method is configure(String), how do i use that on this?

Comment: Hibernate configuration class, please see the link above: http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.2/javadocs/org/hibernate/cfg/Configuration.html

Comment: thx-- will take a look. this the setup in the office and for after the holiday.

Answer (score 0):

**Exact** same code-- both the calling class and DTOs worked in another project i set up from scratch. 
The setup & placement of libraries and the codes are the same, so are the other environment setting (all default Eclipse).

The only difference is the DBs behind and the related config file settings. I used postgreSQL in the former one and set the related tags in config according to that. The DB in the second, the one that worked is MySQL. Outside of these related tags, the **hibernate.cfg.xml** file is the same in the two projects-- the exact same set of tags, and values of non-postgreSQL/non-MySQL properties.

From what I know, **Configure** is a class reading & processing on the config file. and since everything else is the exact same, must be a mistake in postgreSQL setting in the former project.